# Cordova DeviceReady firing in iOS but not Android

Tags: android, cordova

deviceready is firing in iOS but not in Android. I had to remove the android platform due to issues it was having during the build and re added it. I see the cordova.js file in my assets folder, so it's there.

I'm not sure what would cause it not to fire in Android but it would be fine in iOS. Any suggestions? Thanks!